# Editing classes from different classes

Tags: html, css

What I want to do is change the rotation of the element marked in green when hover over any element in orange. I know you can have things like

```
ul li.classname
```

I have tried things like this, but do not think I fully understand the different levels to go through to access different elements.

[image]

The code itself:

```
    <!-- Begin Links To Different Pages -->
        <nav id="navigation" style="margin-top:-15px;margin-left:-50px">
            <ul style="list-style:none" class="test">
                <a href="index.html"><img id="home-button" src="images/Home_Button.png"></a>

                <!-- Sweets Link -->
                 <li class="sweets-tabVis"><a href="ProductsPage.html"><img id="sweets-button" src="images/Sweets_Button.png"></a></li>
                 <ul style="list-style:none" class="sweets-tabInVis">

                    <li class="test"><a href="ProductsPage.html"><img  src="images/AllSweets_Button-Dropdown.png"></a></li>       

                    <!-- Begin Type Tab -->
                    <li class="type" style="margin-top:-6px;"><a href="http://www.google.co.uk"><img  src="images/Type_Button-Dropdown.png"></a></li>          
                        <!-- Begin Sublink Type Navigation -->
                            <li class="sweets-sublink" style="margin-top:-62px;">                       
                                <a href="ProductsPage.html" ><img  src="images/Boiled_Button-Dropdown.png"></a>
                                <a href="ProductsPage.html" ><img style="margin-top:-7px;" src="images/Chewy_Button-Dropdown.png"></a>
                        <!-- End Sublink Type Navigation -->
                            </li>                       
                    <li style="margin-top:-7px;"><a href="ProductsPage.html"><img  src="images/Flavours_Button-Dropdown.png"></a></li>       
                    <!-- End Type Tab -->
                 </ul>  


                <a href="ContactUs.html"><img id="contact-button" style="margin-left:250px;" src="images/Contact_Button.png"></a>
                <!-- Begin Links To Different Pages -->
                <section>
                    <img id="search-bar" src="images/Search_bar.png">
                    <input id="search-box" style="position:absolute;margin-top:-70px;margin-left:920px;height:20px;font-family:Hobo Std;font-size:14px;width:150px" value="Search..." type="text">   </input>
                </section>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <!-- End Navigation -->
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Would you edit your question to make it more clear. Your intentions are currently unclear. Specifically: What action on the orange lines causes what effect on the line marked in green?

Comment: Well at the moment, I just want to know how to actually edit those lines (what line of css will grant me access to do this), then I will put in all of the CSS specific later.

Comment: Simple. Open the page in your favourite browser, then right-click an element you're interested in. You can see the styles associated with the element. You'll also get the file and line-number of any css rules that apply. Doing so on your user-name in the above comment in (Google) Chrome tells me that the associated styles are: `a.comment-user.owner`, `a.comment-user`, `a:visited`, `.owner`, `a`

Comment: Ok thanks, I shall give this a try now and let you know!

Comment: No worries.:) I meant to say, when you right-click the element, select `Inspect Element` from the context-menu that appears.

Comment: So how would the line of css look to access the class .owner in the example you gave above then?

Comment: The rule for elements with the `owner` class on this page is: `.owner{background-color: #e0eaf1;}`. You may be better placed to get a useful answer if you state in your question explicitly what you wish to achieve. A common mistake is to state what you think to be the solution and ask how to achieve that. The best approach is to state the desired outcome. E.g - _"I wish to style the highlighted elements, I'd like to make them (and only them) have a text-color of blue."_

Comment: Right Ok thanks, what I want to do is change the rotation of the element marked in green when hover over any element in orange.

Answer (score 0):

In css, there is no way to select a class that contains the class that you are using.

Maybe if you try taking the class above (`test`)?

```
.test > .sweets-tabVis {your style}
```

Comment: hmmm, I have tried this and it is not working. Is it because I have so many nested li and ul tags?

Comment: Sorry i had added a space in your `li` class. Did you try without it?

Comment: Yeah still not working, would it be something like this: .test li.type:hover > .sweets-tabVis 
{
 margin-left:1000px;
}

Comment: Oh right duh they're classes try this `.test > . sweets-tabVis {}`

Comment: Thanks, but still not working. I want it to work if I hover over this line <li class="test"><a href="ProductsPage.html"><img  src="images/AllSweets_Button-Dropdown.png"></a></li>

Comment: if you do `.test > .sweet-tabVis:hover {...}` it works for me